# How to rename disk indentifier?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I created 5 partitions on my portable-drive via DiskUtility.

```
$ diskutil list disk2
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS Documents               200.2 GB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Downloads               200.2 GB   disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Music                   200.2 GB   disk2s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Movies                  200.2 GB   disk2s5
   5:                  Apple_HFS Others                  199.5 GB   disk2s6
```

The problem is DiskUtility skipped `disk2s4` somehow. I've no idea why.
Can I rename `disk2s5` to `disk2s4`?

Comment: I'd enable Disk Utility's debug mode first & make sure that's not just a hidden partition before trying anything else - http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/Enable-Disk-Utilitys-Debug-Menu.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've selected the [`Master Boot Record`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) option. Only 4 primary partitions are allowed. `disk2s5` and `disk2s6` are actually extended partions. You cannot change the name conversion via DiskUtility.

If you select [`GUID Partiton Table`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) option, you'll get this:

```
$ diskutil list disk2
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Documents               200.0 GB   disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Downloads               200.0 GB   disk2s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Movies                  200.0 GB   disk2s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS Music                   200.0 GB   disk2s5
   6:                  Apple_HFS Others                  199.2 GB   disk2s6
```